# Can JasperReports Server deliver a report via email with a read-receipt request?

Tags: jasperserver

We have a JR 6.0.x server and we'd like to email reports to people and get read-receipts. Is that something that is possible to do?

Simply adding an arbitrary SMTP header would work, too, since that's all a read-receipt requires. If JR server doesn't support read-receipts directly, is there a way to add headers to the delivery messages?